# Laravel: Ajax using problem always return error 500

Tags: ajax, laravel, csrf, http-status-code-500

Good day.
Trying to send GET method using Ajax and always getting error 500. CSRF used but I can't find where is error. This is my code:

blade

```
.....
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
.....
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            let infoModal = document.getElementById('Modal_UserEdit');
            infoModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function () {
                let userId = document.getElementById("_Input_UserID").value;

                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });

                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('settings.user.show') }}",
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}', id: userId },
                    success: function(data) {

                        console.log(data);

                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('settings/users/user/show', [UserController::class, 'show'])->name('settings.user.show');
```

UserController.php

```
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $request->only(['id']);
        $user = DB::table('users')->where('id', $form['id'])->first()->toJson();
        return $user;
    }
```

Don't think this is CSRF problem, because:

1. If inside UserController just ask something like dd($form) it returns
2. If disable CSRF in Kernal.php - nothing changed...

Somebody please help to understand what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Delete everything from `storage/logs/laravel.log`, make another request and check what is the error (paste the error into edited question).

Comment: erase log file, sent couple requests - file empty (

Comment: set `APP_DEBUG=true` and come back with error

Comment: APP_DEBUG=true
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

still nothing....

Comment: [2022-03-20 15:22:06] local.ERROR: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Cannot use object of type stdClass as array at D:\\src\\OpenServer\\domains\
ms\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Settings\\UserController.php:43)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.
Thank for log reminder )))

Fixed code:

```
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $request->only(['id']);
        $user = DB::table('users')->where('id', $form['id'])->first();
        return json_encode($user);
    }
```